# How to callbacks events like bind in incr tcl?

Tags: itcl

For example I tried this:

```
package require Itcl
package require Tk

::itcl::class X {
    constructor { } {
    canvas .c -height 200 -width 200
    bind .c <ButtonPress-1> {::itcl::code $this A}
}
method A { } {
    puts "inside A"
}
}
X aa
```

but after clicking mouse on canvas it is not going inside method A ?
Kindly help me here .

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :
change  {::itcl::code $this A} to [::itcl::code $this A]